# Cognito: Using admin_user_global_sign_out in pre_authentication trigger sometimes fail due to apparent async behavior

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to sing-out all old sessions from Cognito for a specific user credentials (revoke the Refresh tokens) when a new session is started using the same user credentials (in this case e-mail and password). This way the old sessions won't be able to renew the ID and access tokens with an revoked refresh token. The goal is to prevent two users to be signed in at the same time with the same credentials.

> Note: I know ID and Access tokens are still usable until they expire with the old sessions

The best way I found to do that is via the`pre-authentication` lambda triggered by Cognito. My tests this far are basically running the following piece of code:

```py
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    user_pool_id = event['userPoolId']
    email = event['request']['userAttributes']["email"]
    # Signs out all current active sessions so only this session 
    # being created remains active
    client.admin_user_global_sign_out(
        Username=email,
        UserPoolId=user_pool_id)
    sleep(1)
    return event
```

In the first tests I did, I didn't have the `sleep(1)` as part of the source code. However, by that time, I noticed that the authorization failed from time to time. My first guess was that maybe the `admin_user_global_sign_out` is an async operation and it could be the case that between the time of signing out all old sessions and finish creating the new session, the `admin_user_global_sign_out` was delayed and executed after the new session was created, causing all the sessions (including the new one) to be revoked.

After adding this 1 second sleep, the number of failures of new sign ins dropped significantly (I have run this flow a ten of times and didn't see any errors anymore). Maybe this one second sleep has been enough to complete the sing out of all current active sessions before proceeding with the creation of the new one.

However as we know, things can go wrong with async distributed system if some part of the system becomes slower than the others, and I'm afraid that in the event of a sign out delay higher than 1 second I can face again the same problems in the future.

So my questions are:

- Is `admin_user_global_sign_out` an async operation and are my assumptions are right?
- Is there a way to make this global sing out a synchronous operation? Maybe via on waiting some state change by calling Cognito APIs?

Answer (score 1):

In boto3, Cognito's global_sign_out and admin_user_global_sign_out methods do not wait for Cognito to complete its operation.
What we can do is to get a refresh token and repeat the process of validating the refresh token and wait for a valid refresh token to come out.

The code below is an example of solving the requirements through the polling process I suggested.

```py
import boto3

cognito = boto3.client("cognito-idp")

COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID = ""
COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID = ""


def login(username, password):
    # Request cognito to invalidate all refresh tokens.
    cognito.admin_user_global_sign_out(
        UserPoolId=COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
        Username=username,
    )

    while True:
        # Generates a new refresh token.
        auth = cognito.initiate_auth(
            AuthFlow="USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
            AuthParameters={"USERNAME": username, "PASSWORD": password},
            ClientId=COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        )
        id_token = auth["AuthenticationResult"]["IdToken"]
        access_token = auth["AuthenticationResult"]["AccessToken"]
        refresh_token = auth["AuthenticationResult"]["RefreshToken"]
        try:
            # Validate that the refresh token you generated is valid.
            cognito.initiate_auth(
                AuthFlow="REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
                AuthParameters={"REFRESH_TOKEN": refresh_token},
                ClientId=COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
            )
        except cognito.exceptions.NotAuthorizedException:
            continue  # If the refresh token is not valid, regenerate it.
        else:
            break  # A valid and only refresh token has been created.

    return {
        "id_token": id_token,
        "access_token": access_token,
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
    }
```

Comment: That's an insightful solution, however I have to points.
1. Do you have the link pointing out that `global_sing_out` is asynchronous? 2. The pre-auth trigger seems a better place to attach this logic otherwise I'll have to add an extra layer on top of Cognito and make sure all clients call my new code to authenticate instead of using Cognito directly.

Comment: No document says `global_sing_out` is asynchronous. It just seems to work that way from the outside.  Since I used Cognito through SDK on backend, I solved the problem by simply waiting for Cognito to complete its operation. 
 However, as you pointed out, if you are using Cognito directly, I think using pre-authentication is a much clearer way.  And honestly, the way `global_sing_out` behaves asynchronously, contrary to the description in AWS official documents, makes me very confused. If you find the relevant information, please share it here.

Comment: And as you know, if you use pre-auth trigger, this method is not available because initiate_auth calls the lambda recursively. It seems appropriate to ask AWS for help. I'm sorry I didn't help you.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @clomia, this actually showed me other options to consider on my design. I didn't get your last comment about the `initiate_auth`. I have been using the library `pycognito` that calls the `initiate_auth` passing the `AUTH_FLOW=USER_SRP_AUTH` (that's expected), and this flow actually triggers the pre-auth trigger fine.